# Why cannot linking -lboost_system it just dont work

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, qmake

Tried to build start WT project in QT Creator with qmake.
Had linking error with -lboost_system, it just didnt work.

**Errors:**

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++  -o Kursach main.o   -lwt -lwthttp
-lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -lpthread    /usr/bin/ld:
warning: libboost_thread.so.1.58.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so,
not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /usr/bin/ld: warning:
libboost_system.so.1.58.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not
found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /usr/bin/ld: warning:
libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libwt.so, not
found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /usr/bin/ld: warning:
libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0, needed by
/usr/local/lib/libwthttp.so, not found (try using -rpath or
-rpath-link) /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libwt.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' /usr/bin/ld:
/usr/local/lib/libwt.so: undefined reference to
`boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/bin/ld:
/usr/local/lib/libwt.so: undefined reference to
`boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*,
boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Makefile:141:
Kursach] Error 1 16:29:43: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with
code 2. Error while building/deploying project Kursach (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
```

**.pro file:**

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
CONFIG   += c++17
#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost/
LIBS +=  -lwt -lwthttp \
    -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system \
    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Wt/WApplication.h>
#include <Wt/WBreak.h>
#include <Wt/WContainerWidget.h>
#include <Wt/WLineEdit.h>
#include <Wt/WPushButton.h>
#include <Wt/WText.h>

class HelloApplication : public Wt::WApplication
{
public:
    HelloApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env);

private:
    Wt::WLineEdit *nameEdit_;
    Wt::WText *greeting_;
};

HelloApplication::HelloApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
    : Wt::WApplication(env)
{
    setTitle("Hello world");

    root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WText>("Your name, please? "));
    nameEdit_ = root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WLineEdit>());
    Wt::WPushButton *button = root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WPushButton>("Greet me."));
    root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WBreak>());
    greeting_ = root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WText>());
    auto greet = [this]{
      greeting_->setText("Hello there, " + nameEdit_->text());
    };
    button->clicked().connect(greet);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, [](const Wt::WEnvironment& env) {
      return std::make_unique<HelloApplication>(env);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are the Boost libraries installed? How did you install them?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude boost installed in standard path by apt-get install boost-all-dev

Comment: Then perhaps a more important question, which version of Boost? Is it version 1.58 as the `wt` library seems to expect?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I have latest version of boost, when i try "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev=1.58" it display "E: Version '1.58' for 'libboost-all-dev' was not found"

Comment: I'm not surprised, version 1.58 is really old. A few possible solutions: Get, build and install Boost 1.58 yourself; Or see if there's an updated binary installation of WT which uses your version of Boost; Or remove your current installation of WT and build it yourself so that it uses your installed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading and installing old version of boost (1.58) was useful, now all is working ok.